# How can I add header text to img alt in HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the below code in `Bootstrap` that display an image:

```
<div class="work">
        <img class="anim" src="1.png" alt="Text1">
        <img class="anim" src="2.jpeg" alt="Text2">
        <img class="anim" src="3.jpeg" alt="Text3">
        <img class="anim" src="4.jpeg" alt="Text4">
    </div>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

How can I add some heading/title to each picture in order to describe the purpose of each one?

Comment: Can you share the relevant CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with Bootstrap grid system and using h3 to insert title of image

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h3>Text</h3>
         <img class="anim" src="1.png" alt="Text1">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h3>Text</h3>`
         <img class="anim" src="2.png" alt="Text1">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h3>Text</h3>
         <img class="anim" src="3.png" alt="Text1">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h3>Text</h3>
         <img class="anim" src="4.png" alt="Text1">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [figure element](https://mdn.io/figure) for this which Bootstrap has [styling](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/figures/) for, e.g

```
<div class="work">
    <figure class="figure">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption">Image 1</figcaption>
        <img class="anim figure-img" src="1.png" alt="Text1">
    </figure>
     <figure class="figure">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption">Image 2</figcaption>
        <img class="anim figure-img" src="2.png" alt="Text2">
    </figure>
     <figure class="figure">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption">Image 3</figcaption>
        <img class="anim figure-img" src="3.png" alt="Text3">
    </figure>
     <figure class="figure">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption">Image 4</figcaption>
        <img class="anim figure-img" src="4.png" alt="Text4">
    </figure>
</div>
```